Which relay can I use that can be activated by closing the loop, in this case water?
I have a plate that is about 1cm deep. Plate is being filled by the pump and I would like to have the pump cutoff once the plate is filled with water.
Floating switch won't work due to the shallow plate.
Is there any way that I can simply put two wires inside the plate and once water touches them and closes the loop, it would close the pump at the same time?

(Wanting the pump to not run when the additional water might flow from the plate would be a bit different: the plate may be tilted, hot (water boiling over), deformed (e.g. resonating); there may be "wind"…)

It's not clear what additional constraints you have, but perhaps you could consider weighing the plate.  If you know it starts empty, you could fill a accurate-sized "tank" with the right amount.  Or a float and lever to magnify the movement, with optical sensor.

Yes, what you describe is perfectly feasible. But you'd need more than just 2 wires with water touching them to close the loop. Googling "electronic water level sensor circuit" should give you some ideas.

yes, you can use a Darlington (or two) to switch it with very low current.

There are many DIY water level sensors out there but not always reliable. or they stay wet. Best is a miniature water level sensor with a 5V relay board.
Put the snesor into a plastic peanut butter container. NB add some larger holes into the lid so that bubbles don't disable the float.
Float sensor
Relay Board


Hey, thanks for your reply. I assume by placing it inside a container, it wouls get lifted together with the container thus switching off the pump? Also, no solution by using the two exposed wires?

I put some small stones into my container to prevent the container from lifting up. I will add pic to answer.

other solutions:
https://www.google.com/search?q=water+level+circuit+sensor

I would put the stones  (or a brick with a hole through it, or a large steel nut) on top of the lid, and put an aditiional wide float under the small sensor float.
